# Ubuntu does not load, missing initrd.img-3.0.5-17-generic

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on an AMD HP computer.  To install a recent update I had to clear some files out of /boot, and I stupidly erased a bunch of initrd.img packages that I mistook for useless files.  I am a newbie.  So now Ubuntu does not load at all.  I can boot from a disk to access the files on my computer, but I don't know how to fix this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Boot a live cd, or just the ubuntu install cd, choose "Try out", then open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo su
mkdir -p /mnt/disk
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/disk
chroot /mnt/disk
update-initramfs -u
```

That assumes that you installed ubuntu on the first partition of your first harddisk. You have to alter `/dev/sda1` otherwise. Also i recommend you to use the install-cd that you used to install your ubuntu.

Good luck!